# React-native 0.60.x app crash immediatelly

Tags: android, react-native

After migrating from 0.59.x to 0.60.x export on iOS works perfect, but when I'm trying to run `react-native run-android`, it build success, but in emulator app just open and close with message:

> App keeps stopping

In console I have just

> Starting: Intent { cmp=com.mycompany/.MainActivity }

and it shows cursor again. Without any errors  or messages. I updated gradle.properties with

```
android.enableJetifier=true
android.useAndroidX=true
```

Also root build.gradle changed  classpath  for dependencies:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'
```

and in gradle-wrapper.properties

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.1-all.zip
```

How can I fix that, or  just show some  error and debug app crashes?

package.json is this:

```
"dependencies": {
    "native-base": "^2.13.8",
    "react": "16.6.3",
    "react-native": "^0.60.5",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.4.1",
    "react-native-svg": "^9.0.7",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.2.0",
    "react-native-webview": "^7.0.7",
    "react-navigation": "^3.0.9",
    "react-redux": "^6.0.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-persist": "^5.10.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "rn-fetch-blob": "^0.10.16"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-jest": "24.0.0",
    "jest": "24.0.0",
    "jetifier": "^1.6.4",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.51.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.6.3",
    "react-timer-mixin": "^0.13.4"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
```

What I'm missing?

**Edit** After run `gradlew  installDebug --stacktrace` I got this response:

```
07:20:21 V/ddms: execute: running am get-config
07:20:21 V/ddms: execute 'am get-config' on 'emulator-5554' : EOF hit. Read: -1
07:20:21 V/ddms: execute: returning
Installing APK 'app-debug.apk' on 'Pixel_2_API_28(AVD) - 9' for app:debug
07:20:21 D/app-debug.apk: Uploading app-debug.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
07:20:21 D/Device: Uploading file onto device 'emulator-5554'
07:20:21 D/ddms: Reading file permision of /Users/kristian/Documents/Work/Roche/roche-mobile-app/android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk as: rw-r--r--
07:20:21 V/ddms: execute: running pm install -r -t "/data/local/tmp/app-debug.apk"
07:20:21 V/ddms: execute 'pm install -r -t "/data/local/tmp/app-debug.apk"' on 'emulator-5554' : EOF hit. Read: -1
07:20:21 V/ddms: execute: returning
07:20:21 V/ddms: execute: running rm "/data/local/tmp/app-debug.apk"
07:20:22 V/ddms: execute 'rm "/data/local/tmp/app-debug.apk"' on 'emulator-5554' : EOF hit. Read: -1
07:20:22 V/ddms: execute: returning
Installed on 1 device.

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 5.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/4.10.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
```

Error  post from `adb  logcat`

```
09-20 19:51:02.507  6478  6478 I MicroDetectionWorker: onReady
09-20 19:51:02.508  2061  2294 D EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xebc05600: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xebc03d10)
09-20 19:51:02.509  6478 16903 I MicrophoneInputStream: mic_close  SR : 16000 CC : 16 SO : 6
09-20 19:51:02.509  6478 17179 I MicroRecognitionRunner: Detection finished
09-20 19:51:02.509  6478 17179 W ErrorReporter: reportError [type: 211, code: 524300]: Error reading from input stream
09-20 19:51:02.510  6478  6546 I MicroRecognitionRunner: Stopping hotword detection.
09-20 19:51:02.510  6478 17179 W ErrorProcessor: onFatalError, processing error from engine(4)
09-20 19:51:02.510  6478 17179 W ErrorProcessor: com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.speech.b.g: Error reading from input stream
09-20 19:51:02.510  6478 17179 W ErrorProcessor:        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.microdetection.d.k.a(SourceFile:91)
09-20 19:51:02.510  6478 17179 W ErrorProcessor:        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.microdetection.d.l.run(Unknown Source:14)
09-20 19:51:02.510  6478 17179 W ErrorProcessor:        at com.google.android.libraries.gsa.runner.a.a.b(SourceFile:32)
09-20 19:51:02.510  6478 17179 W ErrorProcessor:        at com.google.android.libraries.gsa.runner.a.c.call(Unknown Source:4)
09-20 19:51:02.510  6478 17179 W ErrorProcessor:        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
09-20 19:51:02.510  6478 17179 W ErrorProcessor:        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:458)
09-20 19:51:02.510  6478 17179 W ErrorProcessor:        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
09-20 19:51:02.510  6478 17179 W ErrorProcessor:        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.b.g.run(Unknown Source:4)
09-20 19:51:02.510  6478 17179 W ErrorProcessor:        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.b.aw.run(SourceFile:4)
09-20 19:51:02.510  6478 17179 W ErrorProcessor:        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.b.aw.run(SourceFile:4)
09-20 19:51:02.510  6478 17179 W ErrorProcessor:        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
09-20 19:51:02.510  6478 17179 W ErrorProcessor:        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
09-20 19:51:02.510  6478 17179 W ErrorProcessor:        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
09-20 19:51:02.510  6478 17179 W ErrorProcessor:        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.b.i.run(SourceFile:6)
09-20 19:51:02.510  6478 17179 W ErrorProcessor: Caused by: com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.exception.GsaIOException: Error code: 393238 | Buffer overflow, no available space.
09-20 19:51:02.510  6478 17179 W ErrorProcessor:        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.Tee.j(SourceFile:103)
09-20 19:51:02.510  6478 17179 W ErrorProcessor:        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.au.read(SourceFile:2)
09-20 19:51:02.510  6478 17179 W ErrorProcessor:        at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:101)
09-20 19:51:02.510  6478 17179 W ErrorProcessor:        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.ao.run(SourceFile:17)
09-20 19:51:02.510  6478 17179 W ErrorProcessor:        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.an.run(SourceFile:2)
09-20 19:51:02.510  6478 17179 W ErrorProcessor:        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:458)
09-20 19:51:02.510  6478 17179 W ErrorProcessor:        ... 10 more
09-20 19:51:02.510  6478 17179 I AudioController: internalShutdown
09-20 19:51:02.512  6478 14804 I DeviceStateChecker: DeviceStateChecker cancelled
```

Comment: Did you try uninstalling the app before running it again?

Comment: Yes I tried, same result

Comment: Post the stack trace.  That tells you what the error is.  WIthout that., we can't tell you anything.

Comment: But there is no stacktrace, app immediatelly crash, and in console there is just that Starting: Intent { cmp=com.mycompany/.MainActivity

Comment: I edited  post with response from stacktrace

Comment: post stacktrace from `adb logcat`

Comment: I  attached that, is that what you need?

Answer (score 1):

Finally found a way how to fix this issue.

**STEP 1**

First unlink all stuffs

```
react-native unlink ...
```

Then **remove node_modules** and update `native-base`, `react-native`, `react-native-gesture-handler`, `rn-fetch-blob` to latest versions (**if** you have them in *package.json*). Install `jetifier` library. Then **install node modules again** and then run

```
react-native link
```

**STEP 2**

After that on build.graddle under android folder, change

```
classPath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
```

into

```
classPath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'
```

And under allprojects/repositories change

```
repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
    }
```

into

```
repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
        maven {  
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }   
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
```

**IMPORTANT** - order of stuffs must be changed!

**STEP 3**

Then next step is to add new lines into  gradle.properties

```
android.useDeprecatedNdk=true
android.enableJetifier=true
android.useAndroidX=true
```

**STEP 4**
change build.gradle in android/app folder, under definitions add new line:

```
def useIntlJsc = false
```

Under android block above defaultConfig add theese lines:

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

And under dependencies add those lines:

```
if (useIntlJsc) {
    implementation 'org.webkit:android-jsc-intl:+'
} else {
    implementation 'org.webkit:android-jsc:+'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this method (For android)**

cd into android folder

run `gradlew clean` or `./gradlew clean` according to your OS

Now run `react-native run-android` it worked for me in android.

**Try this method (For ios)**

For iOS try deleting pods folder and `pod install`

[Reference](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview/issues/777#issuecomment-574530147)